# HTTP Callout returns HTML - can I load it into a new browser window?

Tags: javascript, callout, html

I'm currently making a callout to a third party api from some Apex code triggered by a javascript button, sending info to fill out a web form on their end. The desired functionality is that the button cause a browser window to open with the filled out web form.

The way we've set it up currently, when I do a `system.debug()` statement on the callout response's body, it shows the html code for the web form. So I assume I'm basically being fed an html file as a response.

I'm wondering if its possible to load this html in a browser window from my Apex code, and how. Could I create a VF page on the fly and load the code into that?

Or is this even possible? Part of me wants to go to the other party and tell them to host their own web form and send me a URL in the response, in the hopes that I could use the javascript button to open a browser and point to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible using the following JavaScript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

var html = sforce.apex.execute("MyClass","myMethod",{}"});    
var win = window.open();
win.document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

But it comes with the caveat that you understand XSS attacks, and the risks that you would open yourself up to in allowing this. You probably want to read the security documentation provided by Salesforce:

- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_xss.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks! One thing though: the CSS and image links that are included in the HTML are not showing up. Is this because we're only using 'innerHTML'? Should I be looking up other javascript commands for including CSS and external image links, etc?

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Keats says, big red warning signs about XSS attacks.

It's not 100% clear from your question whether you're doing this in Javascript or Apex. If it's an Apex controller, you can save the html into a String variable with getters/setters then use `<apex:outputtext>` in the Visualforce

e.g.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!myHtml}" escape="false"/>
```

The `escape="false"` bit will allow your string to be interpreted as html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I myself was unsure of whether I should try loading the retrieved html using Apex or JS. Mark Keats' solution using JS should work for me though! I will definitely read about the XSS attacks.